# Container of shared_ptr with different type?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

How to create a `std::map` for all kinds of shared_ptrs?

I need a map (key is `string`) contains different type `shared_ptr`s, for example:

```
XXXXXX myMap = {
{"B", make_shared<B>()}, 
{"C", make_shared<C>()}
};
```

class `B` and `C` has no relationship.

How to define `myMap`?

Comment: Smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). How are you going to use the map if you don't know the types of the elements?

Comment: That sounds like it might become a problem when you want to access the elements. How could you ( **or the typesystem** ) know what the type of an element is? It could be `B` or `C`. For dynamic code, there is no way to know.

Comment: I use the key of the map to cast them to B or C.

Comment: @Zach Is it just the two types? Can't you just use two maps?

Comment: @Biffen, no. There are many classes.

Comment: So every time you access elements of this map, you have to do a gigantic `switch` of casts? Sounds like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: The whole idea sounds a bit like a flawed design, tbh

Comment: @Angrew, to get the value, I use `auto v = (shared_ptr<B>)map.at("B")`, no switch case.

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr` supports semantic of raw pointers. And all raw pointers can be converted to `void*`. So to create a `map` containing `shared_ptr` of any type you should use the following: `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<void>>`